# NativeScript VSCode extension intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

I've installed the latest NativeScript extension for Visual Studio Code (https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-for-visual-studio-code). Supposedly the extension does support intellisense: "With Intellisense, interactive debugging and integration with device emulators, the NativeScript extension for Visual Studio Code provides the most feature complete environment for NativeScript Development". However, in my Page.xml files there is no such thing as intellisense. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative if you are ok working with `React` in `NativeScript`is to use [react-nativescript](https://github.com/shirakaba/react-nativescript). It gives you Intellisense you would expect like this:

[image]